# Markup text blocks with multiple citations in HTML

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I'm undertaking an ambitious project to organize laws in my country starting with the Constitution.

The text body is arranged in short blocks of text called *articles*, and each article can be modified by a *constitutional amendment*.

The idea is that when someone highlights a particular article, they get a summary of all the constitutional amendments that went into creating this block of text.

---

**Question**:  What would be the best way to demarcate a specific block and cite it?

For example, what would be the best way to replace the `span` tags:

```
<p>
<span data-ammendment-id="1">
<span data-ammendment-id="2">
10A.    Right to fair trial:
For the determination of his civil rights and obligations or in any criminal charge against him a person shall be entitled to a fair trial and due process.
</span></span>
</p>

<p>
<span data-ammendment-id="1">
11  Slavery, forced labour, etc. prohibited
(1) Slavery is non-existent and forbidden and no law shall permit or facilitate its introduction into Pakistan in any form.
(2) All forms of forced labour and traffic in human beings are prohibited.
(3) No child below the age of fourteen years shall be engaged in any factory or mine or any other hazardous employment.
(4) Nothing in this Article shall be deemed to affect compulsory service:-
  (a)   by any person undergoing punishment for an offence against any law; or
  (b)   required by any law for public purpose provided that no compulsory service shall be of a cruel nature or incompatible with human dignity.
</span>
</p>
```

---

These tags aren't valid here:

- `cite`: doesn't provide a way to demarcate a block of text
- `details` and `summary`: aren't appropriate here, since I'm looking to cite the appropriate amendment here
- `blockquote` and `cite`: This would be perfect, except that this is the markup for the original document itself, and so quoting the text wouldn't be appropriate. Especially since some amendments are iterative ("change THIS with THAT at line X") instead of declarative ("replace article X with Y")
- `del` & `ins`: Unfortunately, this is best used in a `diff`, which the final version of the document isn't. It must read like plain text.

Comment: I don't think HTML provides any mechanisms for this. If the citations may appear as links, you *could* get away with putting the links in a footer or something (and you'd need to replace those p and span elements with something else, like articles and/or sections), but from the looks of it the citations are intended to be referenced by their ID, in which case you'd have to settle for custom data attributes (whose semantics are defined only by you and the applications consuming this markup; the attributes themselves don't carry any intrinsic semantic value).

Comment: Maybe the `<ins>` element with the `cite` attribute would be suitable for the _amenments_ (aren't they effectively sort of _additions_?) to the document? It also allows to mark up both blocks and phrase-level fragments.